# Troubleshooting MassTransit request client when using RoutingSlipRequestProxy/RoutingSlipResponseProxy for handling courier activities

Tags: masstransit

Can someone give a working example in ASP.NET Core (with DI) of using RequestClient with RoutingSlipRequestProxy/RoutingSlipResponseProxy? I am trying the following code but somehow my message goes into skipped queue and I never get a reply in the controller action. The code in CreateESimOrderCommandResponseConsumer never gets executed:

```cs
public class CreateESimOrderCommandConsumer : RoutingSlipRequestProxy<CreateESimOrderCommand>
{   
    protected override Task BuildRoutingSlip(RoutingSlipBuilder builder, ConsumeContext<CreateESimOrderCommand> request)
    {
        builder.AddActivity("OrderSaveToDb", QueueNames.GetActivityUri(nameof(OrderSaveToDbActivity)));
        builder.AddActivity("CreatePreactiveSubscriber", QueueNames.GetActivityUri(nameof(CreatePreactiveSubscriberActivity)));
        builder.AddActivity("OrderUpdateStatus", QueueNames.GetActivityUri(nameof(OrderUpdateStatusActivity)));
        
        builder.SetVariables(new
        {
            ProfileId = request.Message.ESimCatalogItemProfileId,
        });
     
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class CreateESimOrderCommandResponseConsumer : RoutingSlipResponseProxy<CreateESimOrderCommand, SubscriberCreationRequested>
{
    protected override Task<SubscriberCreationRequested> CreateResponseMessage(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipCompleted> context, CreateESimOrderCommand request)
    {
        SubscriberCreationRequested subscriberCreationRequestedImpl = new SubscriberCreationRequestedImpl(context.GetVariable<string>("PhoneNumber"));
        return Task.FromResult(subscriberCreationRequestedImpl);
    }
}

public interface SubscriberCreationRequested
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; }
}

public record SubscriberCreationRequestedImpl(string PhoneNumber): SubscriberCreationRequested;

public interface CreateESimOrderCommand
{
    public int ESimCatalogItemProfileId { get; }
}
```

In program.cs

```cs
    builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.AutoStart = true;
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);
            cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
        });
        x.AddRequestClient<CreateESimOrderCommandConsumer>();
        x.AddRequestClient<CreateESimOrderCommandResponseConsumer>();
        x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<CreateESimOrderCommandConsumer>();
        x.AddActivitiesFromNamespaceContaining<ESimOrderSaveToDbActivity>();
    });
```

In my asp.net core controller:

```cs
    private readonly IRequestClient<CreateESimOrderCommand> requestCreateOrderRequestConsumerClient;
    private readonly ILogger<ESimController> logger;

    public ESimController(
        IRequestClient<CreateESimOrderCommand> requestCreateOrderRequestConsumerClient,
        ILogger<ESimController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.requestCreateOrderRequestConsumerClient = requestCreateOrderRequestConsumerClient;
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Generate(ESimGenerateModel eSimGenerateModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var resp = await requestCreateOrderRequestConsumerClient.GetResponse<SubscriberCreationRequested>(new
        {
            ESimCatalogItemProfileId = eSimGenerateModel.ESimProfileId,
        }, cancellationToken);
    
        logger.LogInformation("Resp = {0}", resp.Message.PhoneNumber);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The console logging shows that the message goes to SKIP queue:

```
[10:31:21.994 DBG] [] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/order-update-status_execute?bind=true 0c4f0000-2019-c2f6-cdaa-08db0a78061b MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip [s:MassTransit.Messages]
[10:31:21.994 DBG] [] RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/create-crmpreactive-subscriber_execute 0c4f0000-2019-c2f6-cdaa-08db0a78061b MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip [....].ESim.CourierActivities.CreatePreactiveSubscriberActivity(00:00:00.0552592) [s:MassTransit.Messages]
[10:31:22.137 DBG] [] SKIP rabbitmq://localhost/create-esim-order-command 0c4f0000-2019-c2f6-0750-08db0a780650 [s:MassTransit.Messages]
[10:31:22.140 DBG] [] SEND rabbitmq://localhost/create-esim-order-command 0c4f0000-2019-c2f6-0750-08db0a780650 MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlipCompleted [s:MassTransit.Messages]
[10:31:22.140 DBG] [] RECEIVE rabbitmq://localhost/order-update-status_execute 0c4f0000-2019-c2f6-cdaa-08db0a78061b MassTransit.Courier.Contracts.RoutingSlip [...].ESim.CourierActivities.OrderUpdateStatusActivity(00:00:00.1486087) [s:MassTransit.Messages]
```

For calling the request/response proxy consumer from a saga I came up with the following code:

```cs
public class ESimOrderStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<ESimOrderState>
{
    static ESimOrderStateMachine()
    {
        MessageContracts.Initialize();
    }

    public State ESimOrderSubscriberPendingActivation { get; set; }
    public Event<ESimCreateOrder> ESimOrderSubmittedEvent { get; set; }

    public ESimOrderStateMachine(ILogger<ESimOrderStateMachine> logger)
    {
        Request(() => CreateCRMSubscriber);
        
        InstanceState(m => m.CurrentState);
        Event(() => ESimOrderSubmittedEvent);
        Initially(
            When(ESimOrderSubmittedEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                })
                .Then(x => logger.LogInformation("ESim order submitted"))
                .Request(CreateCRMSubscriber, context => context.Init<CreateESimOrderCommand>(new
                {
                    ESimCatalogItemProfileId = context.Message.ESimCatalogItemProfileId,
                }))
                .TransitionTo(ESimOrderSubscriberPendingActivation)
        );
        During(ESimOrderSubscriberPendingActivation,
            When(ESimOrderCancelRequestEvent)
                .Finalize()
        );
    }

    public Request<ESimOrderState, CreateESimOrderCommand, SubscriberCreationRequested> CreateCRMSubscriber { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure if this is the intended way to make a request using request/response proxies from saga, but when I execute the saga, I get a fault:

```
MassTransit.EventExecutionException: The ESimOrderSubmittedEvent<ESimCreateOrder> (Event) execution faulted
 ---> MassTransit.EventExecutionException: The ESimOrderSubmittedEvent<ESimCreateOrder> (Event) execution faulted
 ---> MassTransit.EventExecutionException: The ESimOrderSubmittedEvent<ESimCreateOrder> (Event) execution faulted
 ---> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: A request timeout was specified but no message scheduler was specified or available
   at MassTransit.SagaStateMachine.RequestActivityImpl`3.SendRequest(BehaviorContext`1 context, SendTuple`1 sendTuple, Uri serviceAddress) in /_/src/MassTransit/SagaStateMachine/SagaStateMachine/Activities/RequestActivityImpl.cs:line 45
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both proxy consumers, the request and the response proxy, should be configured to use the same endpoint. You can use a [`ConsumerDefinition`](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#consumer-definition) for each consumer and specify the same endpoint name in the constructor, or manually configure the endpoint. Both of these options are [documented](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#endpoint-definition).

Comment: It worked; thanks for the guide. Is there any way to call a request/response proxy consumer and wait for a response before executing the next step in a saga? A concrete example would be great.

Comment: There are hours of video on YouTube and a plethora of samples available on GitHub.

Comment: I think I've made some progress, and I've added the saga code in the original question; not sure is the correct approach since it throws a new fault, but literally, I am trying to wrap my head around these concepts since it is the first time working with MassTransit.